# jqGrid 'setGridHeight' not firing in IE

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am adding a custom grow/shrink buttons to my jqGrid title bar to allow the user to change the height of the grid.  The following code works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Internet Explorer (version 8).  In IE, the alerts before and after the call to setGridHeight are working, but the grid is not re-sized.  (And unfortunately, IE is the business's default browser.)  Has anyone come across a similar problem or know a solution?

```
var expand = "alert('start'); 
 $('#grid').jqGrid('setGridHeight', 
 $(window).innerHeight()/1.5); 
 alert('end');";    
$("#gview_grid .ui-jqgrid-titlebar").append 
 ('<a class="ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close HeaderButton"  role="link" style="right: 30px;">
  <span id= "grid_plus" class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus" onClick = "'+expand+'"></span> </a>');
```

[image: Grow/Shrink buttons on title bar]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure this will help, but also just try setting the height using the previous API call like so:
`$('#grid').setGridHeight($(window).innerHeight()/1.5));`

Comment: I had actually tried that as well with no luck.  Also attempted just setting it to a constant instead of the innerHeight.  Thanks for the quick reply, though.

Comment: Did you try turning on 'Debug' mode on IE and see if any errors are being thrown? IE can be very anal about semi-colons and trailing commas.

Comment: can you put this up in jsfiddle?

Comment: @keithxm23: Using chohi's suggestion below, I was able to break on the function.  Each line gets called as expected with no errors, but nothing happens on the UI side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In creating a simplified example to post to jsfiddle, I discovered that the original posted code does indeed work in IE.  The issue was that I had bound the size of grid to the window resize function (and apparently IE did not like that).

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
    $('#grid').jqGrid('setGridHeight', $(window).innerHeight()/3);  
}).trigger('resize');
```

I am still working on a solution so that these can work together in IE, but for now at least we know what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Will it help if you create expand as a function?

```
    var expand = function(){/*...
   */}
```

and call it from your markup as `expand()`?

Comment: Same problem.  I can't put the entire code up on jsfiddle, but I will try to get a simple example that illustrates the issue later today.